# Linux driver privileges

Tags: linux, command-line, drivers, privileges

I've loaded a custom driver to linux via `mknod`. However, now any programs I write to use it need to be run using `sudo`, which is difficult to do when I'm using an IDE. Is there any way to adjust the driver privileges so I can run my program in my IDE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work if you change the ownership and permissions of the device node you've created:

```
chown kalak:kalak node
chmod 600 node
```

(assuming your username is `kalak`, your main group is `kalak` and your device node is called `node`).

Comment: Thanks. I'm coming into Linux with little idea of what I'm doing. Taking over someone else's project can be a big learning experience